# Grey Spots Cover Visibility of Vertices, Edges, Faces

Tags: modeling

Pictured below is a super annoying thing I can't tolerate anymore. How can anyone model when the edges and vertices are hidden under this gray film? This is just one object so there are no intersecting surfaces. Anyone know how I can fix this? I'd really appreciate it!

[image: Here is the problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ist the subdiv modifier. The cage and the shrinked mesh are intersecting each other.

You could either shrink the cage or toggle x-ray as shown in my screenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Greetings